# "Not enough storage to process this command. (8)" I can't hibernate

Tags: windows, cmd, shutdown

"Not enough storage to process this command. (8)" That's what it says when I try and hibernate the computer. The only way I can hibernate it is to close ALL the windows, but that defeats the purpose. I'm confused as to why it worked before and why it suddenly doesn't. I have a crappy Dell laptop with Malware Bytes and ASC6(Advanced SystemCare 6). Would those affect hibernate in anyway? BTW This only happens when I try and hibernate the computer. I would like to know if there are any fixes. Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Is this a Windows alert or does it come from a different program

Comment: Well, what happened is when I click the hibernate button in the start menu it will darken the screen and then go right back to the lock screen, so what I did is I opened the command prompt and typed "shutdown -h" and it did the same thing but when I came back it said "Not enough storage to process this command. (8)"

Comment: Check the `Event viewer` and see if there are more clues there.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Try to delete the 'DumpFilters' key in HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl.

Story

The same error appeared to me yesterday, after stumbling around a bit I found that in my Event Viewer there was something like

volmgr - Event 45: The system could not sucessfully load the crash dump driver

Together with "Not enough storage to process this command. (8)" I could find the following document with google: http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/9499-no-hibernate-volmgr-error-event-id-45-system-log.html.

This page states that a Truecrypt driver (Truecrypt.sys) was the problem, however Truecrypt was never installed on my system. I looked into this registry path anyway and found that a driver was registered in "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\CrashControl" in the "DumpFilters" key.

I deleted this DumpFilters key (which had a value of 'dumpfve.sys', of course not without backup) and lo and behold my computer went into a working hibernate. Because I don't really know much about Windows internals maybe somebody can further elaborate what we break (or not break) by deleting this key?

Note that this seems to be still valid on the newest Windows generation (as I'm using Windows 8.1)